# JavaScript Algorithm For Continuous Filtering Data On Most Recent Results

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to write an algorithm where the user selects an option to filter a particular data and on every click it makes an api request returning the filtered data. As many times the user clicks it needs to continue to filter out the data. My question is, how can the algorithm save the most recent result and run a for/filter loop on the most recent results? Should I store the most recent results in localStorage in order to further filter the results? And when the user decides to unselect the data that they wanted to filter, it should show the user their previous results. The user should be able to continue to filter until they get the desired data. Please see example below.

```
***DATA***
let data = [
  {"id":0, "name":"John1", "age":29, "city":"seattle", "score": 95},
  {"id":1, "name":"John2", "age":28, "city":"seattle", "score": 95},
  {"id":2, "name":"John3", "age":29, "city":"seattle", "score": 85},
  {"id":3, "name":"John4", "age":30, "city":"austin", "score": 75},
  {"id":4, "name":"John5", "age":24, "city":"austin", "score": 85},
  {"id":5, "name":"John6", "age":30, "city":"aspen", "score": 84},
  {"id":6, "name":"John7", "age":31, "city":"aspen", "score": 100},
  {"id":7, "name":"John8", "age":31, "city":"aspen", "score": 93},
  {"id":8, "name":"John9", "age":35, "city":"denver", "score": 93},
  {"id":9, "name":"John10", "age":29, "city":"denver", "score": 75},
  {"id":10, "name":"John11", "age":28, "city":"denver", "score": 85},
  {"id":11, "name":"John12", "age":28, "city":"denver", "score": 85},
]
```

```
***FIRST USER SELECTED FILTER***
let firstFilter = [{"score":85}]

***FIRST FILTER RESULTS***
let firstFilterdResults = [
  {"id":2, "name":"John3", "age":29, "city":"seattle", "score": 85},
  {"id":4, "name":"John5", "age":24, "city":"austin", "score": 85},
  {"id":10, "name":"John11", "age":28, "city":"denver", "score": 85},
  {"id":11, "name":"John12", "age":28, "city":"denver", "score": 85},
 ]
```

```
***SECOND USER SELECTED FILTER***
let secondFilter = [{"age":28}]

***SECOND FILTER RESULTS***
let secondFilterdResults = [
  {"id":10, "name":"John11", "age":28, "city":"denver", "score": 85},
  {"id":11, "name":"John12", "age":28, "city":"denver", "score": 85},
 ]
```

```
***CURRENT ALGORITHM***

function filterDataList(data, firstFilter) {
  let firstFilteredResults = [];

  firstFilteredResults = data.filter((dataItem) => {
    var throwVar = 0 
    for (let item of firstFilter) {
      for (let key in item) {
        if (dataItem[key] === undefined || dataItem[key] !== item[key]) {
          throwVar = 0
        } else {
          return true
        }
      }



    }
    if (throwVar == 0) {
      return false
    }
  })

  return firstFilteredResults

}
```

Comment: Will each filter always have one object that contains one property?

Comment: Actually yes since on each click it will send one object with one key/value pair to the server. On evey click an api request is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The successive filter selections are really specifying a conjunction of keys and values...

```
age == x AND score == y AND ....
```

Just like an object!

Since users can presumably make these choices more than once, they might produce an errant filter like: `age == x AND age == y`.

Se we really want the query to be a conjunction of *unique* keys with values.

Just like an object!

```
// this expresses a conjunction of unique keys - values
let query = {}

let data = [...]
let filteredData = []

// add a key-value, pair and update the filtered data
function addFilter(key, value) {
  query[key] = value;

  const keys = Object.keys(query);
  filteredData = data.filter(datum => {
    return keys.every(key => datum[key] === query[key])
  });
}

function reset() {
  query = {}
}
```

Comment: Is this allowing the user to filter from the most recent results?

Comment: No. Notice that it only assigns to `filteredData`, never filters it.  Instead this idea filters the whole array each time, adding to the query whenever a new criterion is selected.

Comment: I see what you did there. Which essentially is doing what I am looking for. Allow me to implement this in my actual application. Will get back to you letting you know if it worked or not. Thanks

Comment: Hello - the filter works exactly as I want. Had to slightly some thing up. My only concern is that, after testing, is that when different users are using the application from different computers they are shown the filter that someone else is using. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Is the filter and the data kept in a common database?  This would qualify as a new question where you further describe the system, but it sounds like a common database with a singular filter object. The fix would probably involve associating a distinct filter object with each user.  Feel free to create a different question and link to it here.

Comment: The data is coming from a json file that is saved in the server folder. The search filter is in a different file also saved in the server folder. I created it a different question, how do I link it to here?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array and check if each object satisfies the passed filters. This works with filters having multiple elements and each element having multiple properties.

```js
let data = [
  { id: 0, name: 'John1', age: 29, city: 'seattle', score: 95 },
  { id: 1, name: 'John2', age: 25, city: 'seattle', score: 95 },
  { id: 2, name: 'John3', age: 29, city: 'seattle', score: 85 },
  { id: 3, name: 'John4', age: 30, city: 'austin', score: 75 },
  { id: 4, name: 'John5', age: 24, city: 'austin', score: 85 },
  { id: 5, name: 'John6', age: 30, city: 'aspen', score: 84 },
  { id: 6, name: 'John7', age: 31, city: 'aspen', score: 100 },
  { id: 7, name: 'John8', age: 31, city: 'aspen', score: 93 },
  { id: 8, name: 'John9', age: 35, city: 'denver', score: 93 },
  { id: 9, name: 'John10', age: 29, city: 'denver', score: 75 },
  { id: 10, name: 'John11', age: 28, city: 'denver', score: 85 },
  { id: 11, name: 'John12', age: 28, city: 'denver', score: 85 },
];
let filters = [{ score: 85 }, { age: 28, city: 'denver' }];
const filterArr = (array, filters) =>
  array.filter((o) =>
    filters.every((f) => Object.entries(f).every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v))
  );
console.log(filterArr(data, filters));
```

You can also call `filterArr` as many times as you want.

```js
let data = [
  { id: 0, name: 'John1', age: 29, city: 'seattle', score: 95 },
  { id: 1, name: 'John2', age: 25, city: 'seattle', score: 95 },
  { id: 2, name: 'John3', age: 29, city: 'seattle', score: 85 },
  { id: 3, name: 'John4', age: 30, city: 'austin', score: 75 },
  { id: 4, name: 'John5', age: 24, city: 'austin', score: 85 },
  { id: 5, name: 'John6', age: 30, city: 'aspen', score: 84 },
  { id: 6, name: 'John7', age: 31, city: 'aspen', score: 100 },
  { id: 7, name: 'John8', age: 31, city: 'aspen', score: 93 },
  { id: 8, name: 'John9', age: 35, city: 'denver', score: 93 },
  { id: 9, name: 'John10', age: 29, city: 'denver', score: 75 },
  { id: 10, name: 'John11', age: 28, city: 'denver', score: 85 },
  { id: 11, name: 'John12', age: 28, city: 'denver', score: 85 },
];
const filterArr = (array, filters) =>
      array.filter((o) =>
        filters.every((f) => Object.entries(f).every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v))
      );
let firstFilter = [{"score":85}]
let filteredArr = filterArr(data, firstFilter);
let secondFilter = [{"age":28}]
filteredArr = filterArr(filteredArr, secondFilter)
console.log(filteredArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the filters as an array, not an object:

```js
function filter(data, filters){
    let tmpData = data;
    let result;
    for(let filter of filters){
        result = [];
        for(let row of tmpData){
            switch(filter[0]){
                case 'id':
                    if(row.id   === filter[1]) result.push(row);
                    break;
                case 'name':
                    if(row.name === filter[1]) result.push(row);
                    break;
                case 'age':
                    if(row.age  === filter[1]) result.push(row);
                    break;
                case 'city':
                    if(row.city === filter[1]) result.push(row);
                    break;
                case 'score':
                    if(row.score=== filter[1]) result.push(row);
                    break;
            }
        }
        tmpData = result;
    }
    return result;
}


//test:
let data = [
  {"id":0, "name":"John1", "age":29, "city":"seattle", "score": 95},
  {"id":1, "name":"John2", "age":25, "city":"seattle", "score": 95},
  {"id":2, "name":"John3", "age":29, "city":"seattle", "score": 85},
  {"id":3, "name":"John4", "age":30, "city":"austin", "score": 75},
  {"id":4, "name":"John5", "age":24, "city":"austin", "score": 85},
  {"id":5, "name":"John6", "age":30, "city":"aspen", "score": 84},
  {"id":6, "name":"John7", "age":31, "city":"aspen", "score": 100},
  {"id":7, "name":"John8", "age":31, "city":"aspen", "score": 93},
  {"id":8, "name":"John9", "age":35, "city":"denver", "score": 93},
  {"id":9, "name":"John10", "age":29, "city":"denver", "score": 75},
  {"id":10, "name":"John11", "age":28, "city":"denver", "score": 85},
  {"id":11, "name":"John12", "age":28, "city":"denver", "score": 85}
];

let result = filter(data, [['age', 29], ['city', 'seattle']]);
console.log(result);
```